# How to comment a comment using Django’s comments framework

Tags: django, django-comments

I'm using Django's comments framework to quite similar to the [blog example](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/comments/example/).

Can anyone suggest a solution how to reply to a post comment?

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in your posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible with the framework provided.  (Well, of course it is, it's just Python, but only if you override so much you may as well write your own framework).

Consider using Eric Florenzano's [Threaded Comments](https://github.com/ericflo/django-threadedcomments) application instead.

Comment: Thanks Elf I'm going to check that one out.